# Python: Call for value inside nested class

Tags: python

I'm trying to call for value from class B that is nested in class A and use it in class C.
I'm getting AttributeError:

```
class A():
    class B():
        a = 1
    class C():
        b = 2
        c = B.a + b 
AttributeError: class B has no attribute 'a'
```

I also tried to call From 'A', Pycharm recognize it, but python still get AttributeError:

```
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        a = 1
    class C(object):
        b = 2
        c = A.B.a + b 
AttributeError: class A has no attribute 'B'
```

Does someone have an idea of how to use it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class template (`A`) is not constructed while you're calling `A.B.a`. That is, `A` is not bound yet to a class.

Try this workaround:

```
class A():
    class B():
        a = 1
```

Now create `C` separately (`A` is already defined):

```
class C():
    b = 2
    c = A.B.a + b
```

And reference `C` from `A`:

```
A.C = C
```

This can possibly be done via meta-classes, but could be an over-kill here.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a separate class, I'm trying to stick the formation of nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, the class definition for class A is not complete hence you can not access the classes, variables and methods defined in a parent class inside a nested class.

You can try separating the class definitions though as suggested by @Reut Sharabani.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the class by its name, while the class definition statement is still executed.

```
class A(object):
   class B(object):
       a = 1
   class C(object):
       b = 2
       c = A.B.a + b # here class A statement is still executed, there is no A class yet
```

To solve the problem you must defer the execution of those statements :

- move the all those statements to a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod)
- call them after the classes was defined.

---

```
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        @classmethod
        def init(cls):
            cls.a = 1
    class C(object):
        @classmethod
        def init(cls):
            cls.b = 2
            cls.c = A.B.a + cls.b 

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.B.init()
        cls.C.init()

A.init()
```